# SubSonic Transactions - Inserting to a second table with the return identity from first table

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I am using the code below to update a second table (Info2) with the identity used from the first table (info2.Id = info.Id;). When the second save is carried out (info2.Save()) I get the error: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.".
Can anyone see what I may be doing wrong.

SubSonic version 3.0.0.3 and SQL Server 2005

Thanks

```
                using (SharedDbConnectionScope sharedConnectionScope = new SharedDbConnectionScope())
                {
                    using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
                    {
                        Info info = new Info();
                        info.Desc = "Some information";
                        info.Save();

                        Info2 info2 = new Info2();
                        info2.Id = info.Id;
                        info2.Desc = "More information";
                        info2.Save();

                        ts.Complete();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got the TransactionScope and the SharedDbConnectionScope the wrong way round, try:

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
{
  using (SharedDbConnectionScope sharedConnectionScope = new SharedDbConnectionScope())
  {
    Info info = new Info();
    info.Desc = "Some information";
    info.Save();

    Info2 info2 = new Info2();
    info2.Id = info.Id;
    info2.Desc = "More information";
    info2.Save();

    ts.Complete();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this mistake will follow subsonic users forever. It was wrong in the docs some time ago. To memorize the correct order I always remember that the Connection needs to know about the transaction and thus the transaction goes first. By the dismiss the brackets from the TransactionScope line. Makes it more readable with nested using clauses.

Answer (score 0):

As per what I have written in the comments, the only way I can get this working is using TransactionScope first then SharedDbConnectionScope (thanks Adam) and to add MultipleActiveResultSets=True; (SQL Server 2005) to the connection string.

Anybody have any better solutions or other suggestions?
Thanks

```
        try
        {
            using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
            {
                using (SharedDbConnectionScope scs = new SharedDbConnectionScope())
                {
                    Info info = new Info();
                    info.Desc = "Some information";
                    info.Save();

                    //Test for rollback
                    //throw new Exception("STOP");

                    Info2 info2 = new Info2();
                    info2.Id = info.Id;
                    info2.Desc = "More information";
                    info2.Save();

                    ts.Complete();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```